# Save output files in another folder using Rubber

Tags: compiling, output, rubber

Save output files in another folder using `Rubber` (https://launchpad.net/rubber)

From `pdflatex` if you want get rid of output files you can use the optional argument `-output-directory=target`. Then all auxiliary files and the pdf are saved in that selected directory. For example:

```
pdflatex -output-directory=target <file>
```

I need get rid of output files, but I am using `Rubber` to compile

```
rubber --pdf "$filename"
```

It's possible get rid of output files using `Rubber`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `--into` option.

```
rubber --into target --pdf "$filename"
```